# moment.js and firstDayOfWeek() issue in typescript file

Tags: typescript, momentjs

I want to use `firstDayOfWeek()`, but keep getting the error:

> Property 'firstDayOfWeek' does not exist on type
>   'MomentLanguageData'.

I am using angular2 with ts.

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
// ...
var localeData = moment.localeData();
localeData.firstDayOfWeek();
```

Thank you.

Comment: you might be running into naming conflicts with naming your variable `localeData`, have you tried using a different variable name to see if it works?

Comment: I get this error even with `moment.localeData().firstDayOfWeek();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update d.ts typing declaration file for moments in your project.

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/moment/moment.d.ts

It was fixed recently. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/commit/637e7d6df755e785387d5269cb9287cdc51b8cb7